# How to autonomous localization on TurtleBot?

Tags: localization, navigation, turtlebot, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am very new on ROS and TurtleBot. I have done the tutorial on the TurtleBot where located on this link http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot . The thing is I would like to make a TurtleBot to autonomous localization which means the user have not to localize it by themselves. Moreover, I want TurtleBot can walk thought in a known map, and localize it.

I am working on this tutorial as well which is related to AMCL. http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation , but I don't know it will reach to my propose or not?

So, could you please suggest me what is the first thing I should do?

Best,

Mintra.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12461/how-to-autonomous-localization-on-turtlebot?/) by [Mintra](https://answers.ros.org/users/1573/mintra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're on the right track. [Tutorial #3](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map) from the navigation page is your best bet.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2011-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mintra](https://answers.ros.org/users/1573/mintra/) on 2011-12-26**:
@IsaacSaito Oh I see. Thanks for your information. :)))

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-12-26**:
@Mintra You'll know if you try the tutorial that dragging is just giving the starting & destination position and orientation. amcl_demo.launch contains both localizing and auto-navigation (as it's clear from its name = AMCL).

**Comment by [Mintra](https://answers.ros.org/users/1573/mintra/) on 2011-12-26**:
Thanks a lot Ryan. One thing I found on that page is I have to localize it by drag in the direction where TurtleBot is pointing, right? So, if I want TurtleBot to drive automatically and localize by itself llike this vdo http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWvLX6xmoAw , you have any idea how to do this?